# How to write wave functions for particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

Let's say I want to calculate the $\Delta x$ for a particle in a box. I need to calculate $\langle x\rangle$ and $\langle x\rangle^{2}$ which are done by their respective definitions. but in the definition I need to include the wave function. My question is more general though. How can I determine the respective wave function for whatever situation that I may have?

Comment: When writing expectation values please use either `\langle` and `\rangle` or `\left<` and \right>` rather than plain `<` and `>` as the latter are type set as operators (with extra whitespace around them).

Answer (score 0):

Any wavefunction that satisfies the schrodinger equation is a possible realisation of a physical system if the function meets some additional criteria, like normalizability and continuity or others, depending on the boundary conditions. So basically you have to solve a partial differential equation.

If you have a particle in a box this means that the potential energy operator in the schrodinger equation has a certain given form. The particular solution for your wavefunction also depends on the initial conditions. Any particular solution can be written as a superposition of basis states (this is possible because the schrodinger equation is linear). These will often be the eigenstates of some self adjoint operator, since those eigenstates form a complete basis of the hilbert space. Often one is looking for the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian. These states are called stationary, because the shape of the probability density of finding the particle somewhere ( the modulus square of the wave function) doesnt change with time for these states.

Finding the respective soulution for any given situation can become very difficult very fast and is achieved by many different methods, often one has to use approximation like the pertubation method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)) or the the variation method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_method_(quantum_mechanics)).